# How to calculate corect way the entropy on image?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

When I want to calculate the entropy on an image I got only blank white image. How can I do it in the correct way?

```
def entropy_of_image(image):
    image_gray = rgb2gray(image)
    f_size = 20
    radi = list(range(1,10))
    entropy_tmp = entropy(image_gray, disk(radi[8])) 
    plt.savefig('images/tmpentropy.jpg')  
    return entropy_tmp
```

and I call it like

```
    default_file = 'images/myimage.jpg'
    
    filename = os.path.join(default_file)
    img = io.imread(filename)
    img = img_as_float(img)
    gray_entropy = entropy_of_image(img)
```

doing with thesese:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import data_dir
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage import io
import os
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize, downscale_local_mean
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage import data
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage import data, color
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv, rgb2gray, rgb2yuv
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
```

Comment: Please include your import statements. You are calling a function `entropy` but we have no idea from which package this function comes. I’m sure there are many packages with a function named `entropy`.

Comment: Also, entropy is a concept from physics that doesn’t have a 1:1 translation to image analysis. You wouldn’t be able to measure entropy from an image because you can’t see individual atom’s energy in an image. There are multiple image-based measures that people have compared to entropy. What exactly are you looking to compute?

Comment: I'm talking about scikit image entropy https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/filters/plot_entropy.html

Comment: First of all, that function doesn’t compute information entropy as defined by Shannon, it just counts how many different gray values exist in the neighborhood of a pixel. It’s a neat filter, but not related to entropy. See for example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240465/186531

Comment: Second, when you say “blank white image”, do you mean the  file “images/tmpentropy.jpg” written by your function? Or are you looking at the returned matrix. Because your code never outputs anything of value to that file, it just creates a new blank window and writes it contents to file. You need an `plt.imshow()` call in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the saved `tmpentropy.jpg` . I didn't know that I should call the `imshow()` even if I don't want to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `plt.savefig('images/tmpentropy.jpg')`, what do you think pyplot will write to that JPEG file? You didn't give pyplot any array to write. `savefig` writes the current figure window to file. Because you didn't create a figure window, or write anything to that figure window, there is nothing to save to the file, pyplot in this case apparently prefers to write a blank image over giving an error message.

If you first display your image to the figure window, then `savefig` will have something to write to the file. However, it will be what's in the figure window: the image with axes around it, and lots of white space. It is just like making a screen shot of the pyplot display:

```py
plt.imshow(entropy_tmp)
plt.savefig('images/tmpentropy.jpg')
```

A better way to save an image to file is using an appropriate image file writing function, such as [`imageio.imwrite`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/v2.14.0/reference/_core_29/imageio.imwrite.html), [`matplotlib.pyplot.imsave`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html), [`skimage.io.imsave`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave), etc.

Since you're using scikit-image to read your image file, let's use that to write the output image file as well:

```py
default_file = 'images/myimage.jpg'
filename = os.path.join(default_file)
img = io.imread(filename)
img = img_as_float(img)
gray_entropy = entropy_of_image(img)
skimage.io.imsave('images/tmpentropy.jpg', gray_entropy)
```

(don't have your computation function `entropy_of_image()` write image files, have each function do only one thing!)